# MinionPro conflicts with fnsymbol

Tags: fonts, footnotes

For various reasons, I need to include two footnotes at the beginning of my document referenced with symbols rather than numbers; it does not matter what symbols I use, so long as they are not numbers. I know can do this with:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

some text.\footnote{some footnote text}. some more text.\footnote{some more footnote text}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

This works when I use `mathpazo` or `mathptmx` as my font, but not with `MinionPro`. The MinionPro manual specifically states that the font is incompatible with `amssymb` and `amsfonts`, but even when I comment these out, I get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]` and I get a 1-page output file with just the title. As soon as I revert to a font other than `MinionPro`, the problem disappears and the whole document compiles without a hitch. Similarly, if I keep `MinionPro` as the font but declare only one non-numeric footnote, everything goes smoothly.

Comment: Can you post a Minimal non-Working Example? Also, since there are many versions of `MininionPro`, it would be helpful to know the version of the package. What is the second `\renewcommand` supposed to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this works: I've defined another series of ‘symbolic’ footnotes, to be used with the `\footnoteS` command, while standard footnotes are obtained with the `\footnote` command. This requires only the `bigfoot` or `manyfoot` package, and it works with my version of `MinionPro`.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{S}[]
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteS}{\fnsymbol{footnoteS}}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.8\textheight}
Here\footnote{A first,  traditional footnote. } is a symbolic footnote\footnoteS{Another, special footnote. }, and another \footnoteS{Yes,  another! }.

\end{document}
```

[image]